# My Android Studio Project Is Not Compatible With android 9 & 10

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, compatibility

I have an application that is in google play store and it uses `targetSdkVersion 28` and `compileSdkVersion 29` and also `minSdkVersion 21` but when I go to my application page in playstore it says it isn't compatible with my Samsung A30 running android 10.
What is the problem??
I would appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: it's compatible with android 5,6,7,8 but not with 9&10

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set your targetSdkVersion to 28 (Android Pie) due to which you are not able to install it on your Samsung device with Android 10.

> targetSdkVersion specifies the highest possible android API level that
>   the app will support.

You have just provided the support of Android 10 in compileSdkVersion and not for your targetSdkVersion.

Set it to:

```
targetSdkVersion 29
compileSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: I changed ```targetSdkVersion``` to 29 and ```compileSdkVersion``` to 29 and put it on playStore but there was problem again and also I should mention that it is Ok with Samsung phones running android 9&10 in our country local stores and my it installs successfully on those devices.

Comment: Try updating your Google Play Store of your device.

Comment: I checked my phone's playstore version and it's running the latest version of playstore.

Comment: @MohammadAminTebianian Uploading your new APK won't be reflected so soon on the Google Play.

Comment: @hata but when I go to my play console it says that "All updates are live" and when I download my App from another phone running android 7 app was updated to the latest version which upgraded to targetSdkVersion to 29 and compileSdkVersion to 29.

Comment: @MohammadAminTebianian Make sure that on your Samsung phone GooglePlay indicates the latest version in your app's detailed information.

Comment: @hata Checked it but unfortunately, it was the latest version.

Comment: @MohammadAminTebianian Sorry, I have no more idea.